# Server Software used to generate the CSR or which option should i select in server while purchasing a SSL certificate?

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate, server

I am trying to set up https for my application. I followed Comodo documentation to generate the CSR and I have used Keytool(Java) to generate the CSR.

I am purchasing SSL certificate from Comodo and after entering the CSR key I must select the server software used to generate the CSR or Web Server Software from a available drop down list .
There are lots of options, but what look most familiar are:

Apache - ModSSL //
Apache (Ben SSL, Not Stronghold)//
Tomcat//

But which one I should Use ? I am confused about same . My application Specification are :

My Application is build in JAVA . And this Application is deployed on Tomcat 7 and in Tomcat 7 i will install my SSL certificate on a JavaKeyStore. and I have used Keytool(Java) to generate the CSR. And my tomcat is installed on Windows 2012 Server . Please advise .

Comment: Stupid question for them to ask, in the extreme. Server software isn't used to generate CSRs, just readily available tools. In any case, how the CSR was generated is entirely irrelevant. The question is really what format you want the signed certificate in, which depends on what you're going to install it into, not on where you got it from. I would complain about the time wasting this has caused you. Assuming that's what it really says, of course.

Comment: Try going with the nearest thing with T7 (Tomcat 7). Also take support from Comodo guys, as @EJP said.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying on tomcat so the certificate would be installed on tomcat so select tomcat.